# VueJs : Row element ignore the added binding class

Tags: vue.js

I create a table with dynamically created rows. Every rows has a default style, but I would like added "focus" style dynamically with keys (up and down).

It can be seen in the console, that the correct row got focus class, but it ignore its.

template:

```
<tbody v-if="items.length" style="font-size: 13px">
   <tr v-for="(item, key) in items"
       class="cursor-pointer"
       v-bind:class="{'focus': key === focusIndex}"
       @click="$emit('item-selected', item)">
```

Style, indeed vue components:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
.focus {
    @apply .bg-gray-400;
}

.tableStyle {
   ...
   & tbody {
      tr {
         &:nth-child(2n) {
            @apply .bg-white;
         }
         &:hover {
            @apply .bg-gray-400;
         }

      @apply .text-center .bg-gray-200;

      display: table; /* display purpose; th's border */
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box
   }
   display: block;
   max-height: 450px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I think is maybe style issue, but I have not found any solution for it.

Thanks, if you help me :)

Comment: Why not 'actually' focus the row (find element via Vue ref, then element.focus()), and use the :focus pseudoselector, rather than setting an index that tracks which item you've selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of your `.focus` selector there is likely to be weaker than the other styling, so it is overridden by the later `.bg-gray-200`.

Try moving the focus styling to a `&.focus` block inside the `tr {` block, after the other `@apply`.

It might also just be that you are missing a closing brace for the tr block, and did not intend to apply the overriding style (as suggested by the indentation):

```scss
      tr {
         &:nth-child(2n) {
            @apply .bg-white;
         }
         &:hover {
            @apply .bg-gray-400;
         }
      } <-- is this brace missing?
```